# How can I remove weight?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm still learning on how to add weight just so i can animate but i add a LOT of weight on the head, and I don't know how to reset everything.

https://gyazo.com/29159ff8de844e05e033716da0793f1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In weight paint mode, if you click on the ball with colored streaks, there will be a menu. Click on the farthest right icon. It is called 'Subtract', and will remove the weight. I don't know about a complete reset, but this should work. Here is an image:

[image: Subtract Weight]

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Also, if you increase the radius of the brush, you can cover more at a time, so it is more like a reset button.